# python 3 How can a class-method attribute be created by referencing it before it exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-method, class-attributes

I'm trying to solve a codewars problem that I'm not sure has a simple implementation in python.  I want to dynamically create a class-method attribute simply by referencing it before it exists. It sounds so counter intuitive.  How do you initialize a property inside the method when that property doesn't already exist and without setting a value to it from outside?

```
class Thing:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

   @property
   def is_a(self):
      setattr(self.is_a,"is_a_{}".format(???),True)

john = Thing("John")
john.is_a.man
print(john.is_a_man) # this is directly from the cw test
```

Without setting it first (i.e. `john.is_a.man = True`), I don't see how this is possible.  Not that using a try/except would be a good strategy, but I can't even figure out how to catch a reference to a non-existent attribute so I can create it in the handler. Any guidance on this would be appreciated. Or if it's simply not possible with Python, that would be good to know.

https://www.codewars.com/kata/5571d9fc11526780a000011a

Comment: It sounds like there's a much better way to solve your underlying problem.

Comment: I'm open. If I'm going in the complete wrong direction, some re-orientation would be appreciated. I'm not looking for answers please. I just want to know what tools python has to address this.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Codewars challenge so we can see a little more of the context?

Comment: I added the link for the codefights problem to my op. I'm very interested in learning how to do this.

Comment: Use the property setter?

Answer (score 1):

What the CodeWars thing wants is doable, but it's too much magic for too little benefit and a confusing interface, especially the later parts.

```
class IsA(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        setattr(self.parent, 'is_a_'+name, True)

class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.is_a = IsA(self)
```

The `thing.is_a` access doesn't need to do anything special; it's the `thing.is_a.whatever` access that does the magic, so `thing.is_a` needs to evaluate to an object with a hook for setting attributes on `thing`. We implement a Thing's `is_a` as an object whose `__getattr__` sets the appropriate attribute of its parent.